# Android kotlin infix issue

Tags: android, kotlin, infix-notation

I am getting an interesting problem. When I debug my application `isResColorId` is `false`. Unfortunately, `let` function is triggered, and I see `qwe` on logcat.

```
fun drawableTint(context: Context, view: View, colorID: Int, isResColorId: Boolean = true) {
    try {
        val wrap = DrawableCompat.wrap(view.background)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrap, isResColorId then let { Timber.d("qwe"); ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorID) } ?: colorID)
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(wrap)
    }catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException){
        Timber.e(e, "c_id: $colorID coz: $isResColorId")
    }
}

infix fun <T> Boolean.then(param: T): T? = if (this) param else null
```

Logcat:

```
qwe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure about what is going on, you should print `it` inside of the lambda. But what is probably happening is:

```
isResColorId.then(this.let({...})) ?: colorId
```

This means the block inside `let` is always evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to evaluate the second argument of the infix function if the first one is false, you should pass a **lambda** and not a value:

```
inline infix fun <T> Boolean.then(block: () -> T): T? = if (this) block() else null
```

But in this case I would rather write `if (condition) A else B` directly, rather than returning a nullable value which introduces boxing and forces you to check for `null` afterwards using the elvis operator.